# UIAlertView is not visible after bring app to foreground

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uialertview

I'm working on a some iOs project. In this project, i have a process:

1. User register himself in registration page
2. When he press "Register", another page is showed (via `NavigationControler`, with progress idndicator and 'Please Wait' message.)
3. After get response from server, some message in `UIAlertView` is show
4. When user press "OK" on alert, it's moved to next (when everything is ok), or previous (when something go wrong) page.

In most case, this flow works. But in sometimes (not always), when user send application to background/lock the screen while process indicator is on, and then turn app back to active state, `UIAlertView` is not shown. But, then, if user again send app to background and bring it back, message is visible.

Because interaction with `UIAlertView` is needed to continue, it's a problem. I cannot request from user a knowledge, that if no message is visible in this moment, they should turn app back and front again.  I don't know why it is happen, and how to avoid this behavior. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you share some piece of code where you actually popup the `UIAlertView`

Answer (score 1):

When your app is in background you can give the local notification. so according to you if alertview is not coming but still you want that user should know about that something is happen or something is wrong then you can directly use local Notifications.

here is the code -

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

 localNotification.fireDate = self.datePicker.date;
 localNotification.alertBody = self.messageField.text;
 localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
 localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

 NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key
  1", @"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
 localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
 [localNotification release];
```

So when local notification generate user can know about that. And you can navigate the user to directly to application. on clicking off local notification alert. locasl notification alert will come automatically.

here the link for the  more details-
http://www.iostipsandtricks.com/ios-local-notifications-tutorial/

Comment: thanks for you answer, but still: I want only to make sure, that UIAlertView will be visible, after user bring app back to front.

Comment: When the local Notification will generate then it ask for cancel or view. If you press on view it will redirect you to the application where you left it. And your alert-view will be shown. What you need to do it set your alert-view properly whenever your conditions will Correct then definitely alert-view will generate.